Memoized reselect selector with RTKQuery selectFromResult still rerenders component
I'm working with an API endpoint that returns random data for a particular property (unstableProperty) every time it is called for the same entity. This behavior is illustrated below:
// First API Call
GET /entities/3
{
  "name": "Entity Name",
  "message": "This is some entity description",
  "files": [
    { "fileName": "File1", "unstableProperty": "bbserg" },
    { "fileName": "File2", "unstableProperty": "thslkuygseaf" }
  ]
}

// Second API Call (5 seconds later)
GET /entities/3
{
  "name": "Entity Name",
  "message": "This is some entity description",
  "files": [
    { "fileName": "File1", "unstableProperty": "ystgrgazazrg" },
    { "fileName": "File2", "unstableProperty": "strhsryjarehaerh" }
  ]
}

Context
A business rule requires polling this endpoint every X seconds for changes. However, I do not want my component to refresh every time as it includes a table with potentially hundreds of rows, and each row includes a thumbnail. Rerendering the table each time causes performance issues and makes the thumbnails flicker.
Issue
I'm attempting to use this example from RTKQuery documentation to prevent rerendering but it looks like this does not work as intended. Despite setting up a selector that filters out the unstable properties, the component still rerenders every polling interval.
I prepared a detailed example on this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modest-snyder-vyxkxd?file=%252Fsrc%252Fapi%252FbaseApi.ts
Here is how I have simulated the unstable property for demonstration:
let calls = 0;

export const baseApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getTestData: build.query<TestDataResponse, void>({
      queryFn: () => ({
        data: {
          name: "Entity Name",
          message: "This is some entity description",
          files: [
            { fileName: "File1", unstableProperty: `value_${calls++}` },
            { fileName: "File2", unstableProperty: `value_${calls++}` },
          ],
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

My component that shows the issue utilizes this query in the following way:
  const selectOnlyStableData = useMemo(() => {
    return createSelector(
      (data: TestDataResponse | undefined) => data,
      (data: TestDataResponse | undefined) => {
        if (!data) return undefined;

        // Select everything from data except files' unstableProperty
        const stableData = {
          name: data.name,
          message: data.message,
          files: data.files.map((f) => ({
            fileName: f.fileName,
          })),
        };

        return stableData;
      }
    );
  }, []);

  const { data } = useGetTestDataQuery(undefined, {
    pollingInterval: 5000,
    selectFromResult: ({ data }) => ({
      data: selectOnlyStableData(data),
    }),
  });

Despite the selector, the component rerenders every 5 seconds. Everything works as intended if I remove the unstableProperty from the query result entirely.
Question
How can I prevent rerenders caused by changes to unstableProperty while still polling for other data changes using RTK Query?
Please note I can't simply remove this unstable property (e.g., in the transformResponse) because I need the value of this unstable property in other components.

Do you have any way at all to tell when the fetched data actually is different? Anything at all that could be used as a memoization dependency? I fiddled around with your sandbox for quite a while and couldn't make anything work the way you are trying. You are technically fetching new results every 5 seconds, so memoization is pretty busted in your implementation. My suggestion would be to see about memoizing the data property that you are passing down... but again, still, you'd need something of a stable-ish data reference to memoize by.

Maybe polling isn't the best solution for you if you can't provide some sort of stable "updateHash" or "lastUpdatedAt" field in the data. How often does the data actually change? Have you considered sockets or pub/sub and "pushing" updates to clients or pinging them to pull?

@DrewReese I'm not the owner of the API, thus I have limited impact on its design. I talked with the API owner and from what I understand, the unstable property is a hash of file properties. Even if the values used for hashing remain the same, the hashing algorithm still creates a different hash each time. Because of that, I am sure the value for the unstable property will be different every single time I call the API endpoint.

@DrewReese The API requires me to pass these unstable properties for Rename and Delete operations. That's why I need to have them in the store and find a way to rerender my component only when any of the other properties change, excluding the unstable ones. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate your input!

Thanks for the details, that "hash" sounds more like a transaction/synchronization id/token, not very useful for React rendering. Think you could [edit] to include an example of the downstream code that has an issue being rendered too often? If we could see a more complete and representative [mcve] of the problematic code we may be better equipped to arrive at a different or more optimal solution.

@DrewReese of course I can edit and provide more details. I'll spend a few hours on that now and if I don't find a solution I'll update my code. Just an update that I tried wrapping the memoized selector with another selector to add another layer of memoization but that didn't help. I'm not sure what am I missing here - the second selector now gets stable data on input: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modest-benz-dkhw76?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FProblem.tsx

@DrewReese I nailed it! I think I'll post this as an answer: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-farrell-yhmdp8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A30%2C18

There is, a bit hidden in the docs if you ask me, resultEqualityCheck option. It is mentioned here in the example at the very bottom of the page and briefly documented here.
This property does exactly what I need - compares current and previous output and returns new reference only when they are not identical. From documentation:

If provided, used to compare a newly generated output value against previous values in the cache. If a match is found, the old value is returned. This addresses the common todos.map(todo => todo.id) use case, where an update to another field in the original data causes a recalculation due to changed references, but the output is still effectively the same.

The fixed selector looks as following:
const selectOnlyStableData = useMemo(() => {
    return createSelector(
      (data: TestDataResponse | undefined) => data.data,
      (data: TestDataResponse | undefined) => {
        if (!data) return undefined;

        // Select everything from data except files' unstableProperty
        const stableData = {
          name: data.name,
          message: data.message,
          files: data.files.map((f) => ({
            fileName: f.fileName,
          })),
        };

        return stableData;
      },
      {
        memoizeOptions: {
          resultEqualityCheck: deepEqual,
        },
      }
    );
  }, []);

Fixed codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-hugle-xtyt78?file=%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FProblem.tsx

Good finds, thanks for sharing.
